# POST Form Data Cross Domain with CORS

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, amazon-s3, cors

This is my simple AJAX post request using Jquery (I'm trying to upload directly to an Amazon S3 Bucket):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open($("#FORM_ID").attr("method"), $("#FORM_ID").attr("action"), true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        data=xhr.response;
        alert(data);
    } else {
        alert('error');
    }
    return false;
};
xhr.send(formData);
```

However it does not work cross domain.  I understand I need to use CORS, which I'm not familiar with.  I've been scouring the INternet for the past few hours looking for a simple solution.  I've run across several that I've tried to implement, to know avail.  Does anyone know how to replace my code above with an example that will work cross domain?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if the server doesn't enable CORS requests, then you cannot basically do it.

Comment: I did enable CORS on the server ... but let me check if I did it correct.  I don't know if there is special code that I need to do a CORS POST though.  I'll check on the CORS enable now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after days of poking around the Internet, trial and error and conversations with AWS support I figured this out.  This is a PHP solution.  Here is a write up:

http://jay.ligda.net/programming/cors-post-to-aws-s3-using-php-and-ajax/